# Is there any special meaning of writing private at the end of class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, private

I am learning WxWidgets and I found this code in [Cross-Platform GUI Programming
with wxWidgets](https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0131473816/downloads/0131473816_book.pdf) on page no. 30:

```cpp
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
  public:
    // Constructor
    MyFrame(const wxString& title);
    // Event handlers
    void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);
  private:
};
```

Is there any special meaning of writing `private` at the end of a C++ class?

Comment: No. The author may have considered adding additional private members.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it is just a matter of coding style or coding discipline, or habits.

Read [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and some C++ standard draft, e.g. [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

In your particular case, the `private:` is useless, since nothing appears inside the `class` after it.

But future contributors to wxWdigets know at once where should a future private member function be added.

Answer (score 3):

No there is no special meaning. It expresses explicitly, that the class contains no private data or methods. You may consider using a `struct` instead of the `class` and skip the `public:` and `private:` statement.

Answer (score 3):

The `private` keyword in the code you posted in its current form serves no purpose at all. Even if the class had some private member writing `private` is optional as class members are private unless stated otherwise.

But, it is a good practice to put public part of the class on top. The rational is that someone viewing the header files is most likely curios about its public interface. Therefore putting publics on top is useful for readability.

In this particular case, the writer of the class put `private` there to remind future authors of this file to follow the aforementioned style, e.g. public first.

Answer (score 1):

no meaning. that just used for explicit expression.

Comment: "explicit expression" of what? An answer 8 minutes after another one, which more convincingly uses a similar phrasing and explains more understandably, should take more care in avoiding the "copy and hope" impression.